# Numeric-input component not worling as expected

Tags: react-native

I have the + and - overlapping and clicking on them doesn't do anything.

[image]

The code is however basic.

```js
import React from "react";

import { View, Text, Buttonn, FlatList } from "react-native";
import NumericInput from "react-native-numeric-input";

const style = require("@app/components/common/styles").style;

export default class HomeSettingsScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.navigation = props.navigation;

    this.state = {
      homeCitiesNumber: 10,
    };
  }

  render = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        <View style={style.container}>
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: "row",
              backgroundColor: "black",
              width: "100%",
              fontFamily: "DMSans-Regular",
            }}
          >
            <Text style={style.titleContainer}>Settings</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        <NumericInput
          value={this.state.homeCitiesNumber}
          onChange={(value) => this.setState({ homeCitiesNumber: value })}
          minValue={0}
          maxValue={25}
        />
        <NumericInput onChange={(value) => console.log(value)} />
      </View>
    );
  };
}
```

Comment: is the "value" logged anything in the console?

Comment: are you sure that using correct component for NumericInput? the NumericInput compoonet is for inputing values like numbers and you write that clicking does not do anything.

Comment: It's in the documentation of.the component, anyway I'm pretty sure the web version of this is bugged because the same code works well on other plateforms.

Comment: are you using this in the web browser? but you tagged your question as a react-native ...

Comment: react natice is suppose to work on the web  browser as it is specified